# Image not getting uploaded properly to Azure Storage

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to upload my image to Azure Storage. The image does get uploaded on the given path but the uploaded image seems to be uploaded incompletely/cropped. I am uploading different sizes of images on different paths and all of them are having the same issue.

I tried saving these images on local file system and they are saving perfectly.

```
 public static void saveImage(string fileName, Stream fileContent, string contentType)
        {
            
            fileContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = null;

            blob = _blobImageContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            
            byte[] bytes = getByteArray(fileContent);
            bool isCompressableImage = isCompressable(fileName);
            if (isCompressableImage)
            {
                bytes = getCompressedArray(bytes);
            }
            blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).Wait();
            blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
            if (isCompressableImage)
            {
                blob.Properties.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
            }
            blob.SetPropertiesAsync().Wait();
        }
```

```cs
 private static byte[] getByteArray(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

 private static byte[] getCompressedArray(byte[] bytes)
        {
            using (MemoryStream comp = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(comp, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
                {
                    gzip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                bytes = comp.ToArray();
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

Here is a sample of the image being uploaded vs the original image.
[image]  [image]

Only some part of the image can be seen, rest part is not visible.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for getting byte array from stream and also the code for getting compressed image bytes.

Comment: Compared to the original image, is this the top of the image, the bottom of the image or a cropped version of (part of) the entire image? Also, please show us relevant code which might help in solving your issue, like the implementation for `getByteArray`.

Comment: @rickvdbosch  Added the implemented functions. This the top of the image.

Comment: @GauravMantri added. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the actual image you are trying to upload?

Comment: @GauravMantri Shared !

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this unfortunately. I used part of your code and was able to successfully upload and download the file. I used the latest version of SDK though. You can see my code here - https://gist.github.com/gmantri/31553e595ff14381470f4405e35b05d4.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am currently using the deprecated version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob (v 9.3.3). Do I need to upgrade it to v12 SDK ?

Comment: Though it is recommended that you upgrade to the latest version but v12 is quite different than v9.3.3. I even tried just now with the old version and that also worked for me. My guess is that there's something wrong with the way you are getting the `fileContent` stream. Please check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243384/discussion-between-manan-kapoor-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: The error was in the way the byte array was being generated. Thanks for pointing that out @GauravMantri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed between [Manan Kapoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12044920/manan-kapoor) and [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri), adding gist as an answer to help other community members who might face similar issue.

> The problem was in the way the `fileContent` stream was being generated.

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(receiveStream))
{
b = br.ReadBytes(500000);
br.Close();
}
}
```